# Import a custom class in RapidMiner process

Tags: java, rapidminer, custom-operator

I make a custom Stemmer in java and I need a operator for this code.
How can I import a custom Java class in rapidminer 5?

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [nice tutorial](http://rapidminer.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/How-to-Extend-RapidMiner-5.pdf) on rapid-i website on extending Rapidminer. In short, you create a class that extends `Operator`, add some XML decriptors, pack it in a jar with custom manifest and copy to plugins directory.